# Eps files from map export are not containing a vector image

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, geoprocessing

I have made a custom map export service, which exports my map in a range of formats.
However I have noticed that .eps files, exported using the arcPy function:

> arcpy.mapping.ExportToEPS(mxd, Output_File, resolution=96, picture_symbol='VECTORIZE_BITMAP', convert_markers=True)

are not a vector images. The map exported, is not well scalable and it seems pixelated.  Also, we can see that tiled layers and basemaps are not exported as vector images. However in feature/ graphic layers that use picture markers and picture fills will be converted to vector. Any ideas why is that happening? Tile layers cannot be exported as vector images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tile layers are image tiles (unless you are pulling from the new Vector Tiles services), so all the data in them is flattened into an image. There would be no way to 'vectorize' them.

I think ESRI vector tiles are still in Beta development, and I have no idea whether they are planning to allow you to export them as a map other vector formats (eps or svg?), or if it's even possible.